# is there any way to assign a variable to unique to every element in html

Tags: javascript

i have variable "count" in javascript. `function click(e){ var count=0; }` i need to assign this count variable uniquely to every label.`<label id="1" onclick="click(this)>a</label> <label id="2" onclick=click(this)>b</label>`

when i click the label it would call function click(). there the count variable should not be global. the count variable for label id=1 call should different value to that of label id=2 call.

ie label1.count=1
label2.count=2;

is there any way to do like this?????

Comment: FYI: `id` attributes, as well as many other HTML attributes, cannot legally start with a number. You should avoid this as it will cause problems.

Comment: Are you using any javascript frameworks or do you need just plain ole javascript?

Comment: i dont know jquery.. is it possible in jquery???

Comment: i dont use javascript framework....

Comment: @thuk: Everything is possible in jQuery!

Comment: In your click function: count = this.id ?

Comment: Can you give more information on what you're trying to achieve? (this sounds like an XY Problem -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: i need to assign count values unique to element. eg label1.count=1; label2.count=2; changing count variable of label1 should not affect label2. a single variable "count" should be used uniquely to different element......

Comment: is there any way to find whether a <label> is clicked or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to set an arbitrary property on the HTML element.  This is cross-browser, although it's not part of any standard AFAIK.

```
function click(e){
    this.clickCount = this.clickCount ? this.clickCount + 1 : 1;
}
```

If you just want to know whether or not it has been clicked in some kind of toggle fashion, you could set a boolean attribute:

```
function click(e) {
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
}
```

---

If you are willing to use jQuery, it can be slightly more beautiful, using the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
$('label').click(function(e) {
    $(this).data('clicked', !$(this).data('clicked'));
});
```

Comment: is there any way to find whether a <label> is clicked or not

Comment: @thuk I'm sure there's a way. It depends on the context. In a click handler, you could do `if (this.clicked) {`

Comment: actually i want to display "welcome" when a label is clicked . when again that label is clicked need to remove the displayed welcome.. i will create and remove div element using append and removechild element. but the fact is how to check whether the label is clicked ??

Comment: What do you mean, "check whether the label is clicked"? Do you mean "I want to do this when the label is clicked"?

Comment: i need to check whether the label is clicked for firs time or second time.. how to do that??? it must be like true or false. initially the label is false(assuming) when first time it is clicked it must become true then second time false then true and so on.. how to do this...........

Comment: @thuk I've already answered this... You check whether `this.clicked` is true. If not, you set `this.clicked = true`, as in my answer, if it hasn't been clicked. If it is, you know it's the second time it's been clicked.